# fullcalendar how to mark every current date in resource timeline?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar resource timeline and want to mark the current day for every ressource how I make it ? All day cells have the same class name.

currentcode:

```
      <FullCalendar
        ref={ref}
        now="2023-05-05"
        initialDate="2023-05-05"
        scrollTime={milliseconds - 86400000}
        resources={resource}
        // @ts-ignore
        events={query}
        schedulerLicenseKey="XXXX" 
        plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin, dayGrid, scrollGrid ]}
        initialView='resourceTimelineYear'
        allDayContent={(el) => console.log(el)}
        views={{
          resourceTimelineYear: {
            slotDuration: { hours: 24 },
          }
        }}
        locale='de'
        selectOverlap
        stickyHeaderDates
        droppable
        height='auto'
        stickyFooterScrollbar
        aspectRatio={0.8}
        editable={false}
        select={handleSelectDate}
        selectable={true}
       // unselect={(e) => console.log(e.view.calendar.getDate())}
        selectMirror={true}
        //eventChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
        
        resourceGroupField='building'
      />
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now-indicator